# how can i list all the installed drivers on windows & mac OS using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, driver, node-modules

how can i list all the installed drivers on windows & mac OS using Nodejs

is there any npm lib can do this?

the output is like

```
kextstat | grep -v com.apple
```

on mac

Comment: like `driverquery` on windows

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse the `executable`, you can run the command using `execSync` or `spwan`. And get the output and parse. In this case, `kextstat` has to be on the system.

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
const output = execSync("kextstat | grep -v com.apple").toString();
console.log(output)
```

You can learn more here: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

[image]

Comment: i have done that. but it only works on Mac OS .  it doesnt work on windows. i wonder is there any npm lib works on both mac and windows

Comment: what is the equivalent of `kextstat` in window ? Window doesn't seem follow same architechture

Comment: The output is very much difference.. but u can execute a command based on os environment 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/lm--list-loaded-modules-